# Prioritize reading versus writing in the tarantool slave

Tags: tarantool

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to prioritize reading versus writing in the tarantool slave? There is a task which is more important to read than to write, but during writing to the master, the changed records are blocked for some time on the slave. In general, I understand that this is the correct behavior for databases. But maybe there is an opportunity to prioritize reading versus writing on a slave?

Answer (score 3):

all transactions (both read and write) are served in a single thread, there is not prioritization between them.

You can read about it in more details here: https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/1.10/book/box/atomic/